# ckEditor Uploading Issue

Tags: wysiwyg

I installed ckeditor and all went well but now the issue is it can not allow me to upload an Image : when I drag and drop an image it shows a blank line . and if I click on the image icon, it opens but when i try uploading and image it takes me to the page where I was. and nothing happens.do I need any other module to help it upload ? . please I am asking for any help

Comment: Do u find any errors in the status report?

Answer (score 1):

We use a module called IMCE (https://drupal.org/project/imce) to upload images/files via ckeditor. Works really well and has a nice interface.